# Input month as an integer, output the final day of that month

Tags: vba, excel, date, excel-formula

I am trying to write an Excel VBA function that outputs the final day in a month in the format `yyyy-mm-dd` when given only the month number as an integer.

So for January, a `1` would be input and the output would be `2014-01-31`.

I know how to reformat the date using Format(date(), "yyyy-mm-dd") and think I can calculate the last day using DateSerial but am not sure how to input an integer month number into the DateSerial function.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Have you tried using the DATE function?

Comment: Will the year always be the preceding year?  Always 2014?  Or is there some other rule for deciding the year?

Comment: So far as *how to input an integer month number into the DateSerial function*, you merely replace that argument with an integer between 1 and 12 inclusive, as you would for any other VBA function.  I don't understand your confusion on that point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

Function: `=TEXT(DATE(2014, A1 + 1, 1)-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")`

VBA: `DateSerial(Year, Month + 1, 1) - 1`

This function finds the first day of the next month and then subtracts one day.

Paste into any cell except A1 and input your month in A1 to test.

Answer (score 1):

As a formula, with your formatting, assuming the year is 2014 and your month number is in A1:

```
=EOMONTH(41639,A1)
```

Comment: This is far an away the best option. Why use VBA to create a formula that excel already has?

Comment: because this is part of a much larger vba application